# Covering head while sleeping?

Tags: sleep, breathing, risks, position, suffocation

I cover my head with covers while sleeping. I find difficult to sleep without doing it, I feel like there is not enought dark (thought all lighs are turned off and it's really dark) and I simply cannot get sleep without doing it.
I want to know if it's known to cause problems, specially because oxygen might be less inside the covers.